# C++, having trouble catching an exception

Tags: c++

I have been trying to run through the standard exceptions and catch them as an exercise.

I am having trouble with catching out_of_range with the following code in visual studio (windows), instead of my code catching the exception,  instead I get a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime libary popup, "debug assertion failed" .

Am I missing a project setting perhaps?

```
int main() {
    try {
        vector<int> myVector(10);

        myVector[22] = 100;

    }

    catch (const std::out_of_range &exception)
    {
        std::cout << "exception caught: " << exception.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need to use `at`, not `[]`, if you want an out of bounds exception to be thrown.

Comment: `[]` operator does not throw an exception, use `myVector.at(22)` instead.

Comment: In addition to the above: accessing arrays out of bounds (including, but not limiting, to, accessing vectors out of bounds, with `operator[]`) is undefined behavior, and if you do that, there are no guarantees on the behavior of your code.

Comment: Thanks @Tarek Dakhran, tried 
- myVector.at(22) = 10; got it caught by my catch;
Thanks for the Clarification @ Algirdas, so straight to undefined behaviour for the [] operators.